ModuleNotFoundError on google collab
ModuleNotFoundError                       
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d705f0e77d39> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 
     17 import utils
---> 18 from utils.other import new_pickle, load_pickle, new_json, load_json

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.other'

i was trying to install utils.other , it said
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utils.other (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for utils.other

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what module this utils is.  Where are you installing it from?  Is it your own code?

i got the code from github . I am not from a computer background so i dont understand what a module is . i installed the other libraries using pip install on google colab

Python standard library doesn't contains util module still, it's available by third-party providers which is made available on Python Package Index.
On other hand, developers use the word util as a directory name for containing their utilities sometimes as a package.
Hence, you can use pickle and json modules to handle your tasks
import pickle
import json

# Serialize and deserialize using pickle
def new_pickle(data, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)

def load_pickle(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

# Serialize and deserialize using json
def new_json(data, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

def load_json(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)


i tried running this code but still the same error showed . ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.other'

what i am trying to say is don't use those module - instead of that use pickle and json for your file handling, hope you understood.. or ping me with the complete code, I will try to check out that how could I change it in a way that works for you

heyy how can i ping you here? im using stack overflow for the first time and not good with this

just mentioning other names could get them a mail, you can get me through twitter @devkhishan or telegram  anywhere you wish !!! and an upvote would be good if it helped you
